# Cryptic Family Reunion: Flowing ever on

Tags: knowledge, cryptic-clues

The answer to this puzzle is a list of ten thematically related words or proper names or phrases. Each of these is clued cryptically, and the theme is to be determined. Since the definition part of a cryptic clue would give away the theme, these cryptic clues use a family member (e.g., mom, sister) to stand in for the definition part of the clue. So for example, if the theme of the puzzle were chemical elements, "Sister picking at nit" would clue "tin". I hope you enjoy!

1. Ag Hall's final tribute to Grandpa (10)
2. Nephew's nickel display includes rare quarter (8)
3. Father demonstrates wise men's essences (4)
4. Uncle from Rice fixing to spoil Aunt (7)
5. Dad became opposed to Yes, chiefly after "And You and I" (6)
6. "He lit them, I ran," reported son (10)
7. Mom infusing salt water, and yarrow leaves (10)
8. We shan't put out for spouses (7)
9. Old fogey rocks, keeping rhythm with grandma (9)
10. Uncle Henry joins row with fella, getting skinned (8)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Credit to oAlt, Graylocke and El-Guest for helping to complete the answer.

I think the category is

> Rivers of Middle Earth

Answers

> 1. SILVERLODE = SILVER + (hal)L + ODE  (solved by oAlt)
>  2. NIMRODEL = NI + M(R)ODEL (R is quarter of RARE)
>  3. ISEN = (w)IS(e) (m)EN(s)
>  4. BRUINEN = BEN with RUIN inside (solved by Graylocke)
>  5. ANDUIN = AND + U + I + N(o)  (solved by oAlt)
>  6. MITHEITHEL = (HE LIT THEM I)*
>  7. BRANDYWINE = BRINE including AND + Y(arro)W
>  8. ENTWASH = (WE SHAN'T)*
>  9. GREYFLOOD = (OLD FOGEY)* including R(hythm)
>  10. HOARWELL = H + OAR + W(ith) + (f)ELL(a)

Title (thanks El-Guest)

> This is a reference to [The Road Goes Ever On](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Road_Goes_Ever_On_(song)) with "Flowing" indicating the river connection.

Comment: Definitely a strong start! Re: #10, I have a different wordplay that I think is less stretchy, though I see where yours is coming from. Regarding the missing ones, go for a little less obscure...I did not use the Internet.

Comment: rot13(Sbe 1, V oryvrir vg vf npghnyyl FVYIRE + Y + BQR, naq 5 vf NAQ + H + V + A) :0

Comment: ah, and i'm pretty sure OP intended, for 10, rot13(U + BNE + J + RYY).

Comment: @oAlt Ah that makes more sense

Comment: One more to go...think one that figures much more prominently in the action. Also, any sense for the title?

Comment: @JeremyDover rot13(Gur ebnq tbrf rire ba naq ba...)?

Comment: @El-Guest Indeed!

Comment: @hexomino I think 4 might be rot13(OEHVARA juvpu vf ORA sebz Hapyr Ora'f evpr snzr jvgu EHVA (sbe fcbvy) va gur zvqqyr bs vg) ..?

Comment: @Graylocke that's a great suggestion!

Comment: That's it! Another awesome job by all who contributed!